# Number of Ordered Factorisations

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, diophantine-equations

How many solutions does the following Diophantine equation ($\forall \, i$, $x_i \in \mathbb{N}$) have:

$$\prod_{i = 1}^n {x_i} = k$$

where $n$ and $k$ are natural numbers?

Assume you know the prime factorisation of $k$:

$$k = \prod p_i^{\alpha_i}$$

where $p_i$ is prime and $\alpha_i$ is a natural number for all $i$.

For instance, when $k$ is the power of a prime ($k = p^t$ where p is prime and $t \in \mathbb{N}$), the problem reduces to a simple application of [Stars and Bars](https://w.wiki/7gos). We want to divide the $t$ $p$'s into $n$ groups. This can be done in $\binom{n + t - 1}{n}$ ways.

Comment: Have you made any progress in the question? If so, add them to the question.

Comment: I have not made any progress.

Comment: Try decomposing $k$ into its prime factorisation. The solution also seems to also involve combinatorics.

Comment: Assume the prime factorisation is known.

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391/quick-beginner-guide-for-asking-a-well-received-question) + please [avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933): do *some* work. For instance, try first the case where $k$ is a power of a prime number.

Comment: I have incorporated that into the question.

Comment: Excellent! It should now be quite easy for you to derive from that the general case.

Comment: Got it. Thanks.

Comment: You can [answer your own question](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 2):

> For instance, when $k$ is the power of a prime ($k = p^t$ where p is prime and $t \in \mathbb{N}$), the problem reduces to a simple application of [Stars and Bars](https://w.wiki/7gos). We want to divide the $t$ $p$'s into $n$ groups. This can be done in $\binom{n + t - 1}{n}$ ways.

Each prime can be divided separately using this property; the number of ways is:

$$\prod_{i = 1}^r {\binom{n + \alpha_i - 1}{n}}$$

if there are $r$ prime factors.

Comment: +1, but the range for $i$ is not from $1$ to $n.$ it is from $1$ to the index of the last prime factor of $k$ (which should better be named in the question, e.g. $k = \prod_{i=1}^rp_i^{\alpha_i}$).

Comment: Oh right, thanks!